# Titanium -- set top/bottom padding on Ti.UI.TextField

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm struggling with an Android theme issue with text fields. There's too much padding above/below so that I have to set the TextFields to be very tall in order to see the text within.

[image: text field too tall]

In this shot, the "1" is a Label in the box above; the green text cursor is pointing to a little black dot -- that's the text inside a text field (borders added for clarity here). The field is so tall you can't see its text. My layout calls for these text fields to be pretty close together so I can't just make things taller so that the text field fits. I need to remove that padding.

ektheme.xml:

```
  <style name="EKTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextEKTheme</item>
  </style>
```

ekstyles.xml:

```
  <style name="EditTextEKTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
      <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
      <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
      <item name="android:paddingBottom">2dp</item>
      <!-- also tried with 
      <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
      -->
  </style>
```

styles file:

```
"#qty":{
    height: 35,
    left: 0,
    hintText: '',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: 'normal'
    },
    keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_TYPE_NUMBER_PAD,
    verticalAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT_BOTTOM
}
```

I know this xml theme is being applied because without the `android:background = #fff` I get the standard underline in the fields. But, the padding is having no effect. I have also tried setting `android:layout_height` which again has no effect.

Here's a shot of a different field elsewhere in the app (with slightly different styling) that shows how tall the fields are. The green underline shows the field has focus.

[image]

Edit to note that I'm using SDK 5.5.2.GA

Comment: Have you tried the `padding` property? https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that I'm using SDK 5.2.2.GA. The padding property will be available in 6.0. I did look at that, but once you drill down to the details, the new `padding` property sets left and right padding only, not top & bottom which is what I need.

Comment: I don't think there's any effective way or without causing other issues to remove the padding yet. that's why I always follow Android Design guidelines to keep the TextField same as it is in Google Design guides and it works really well. But it depends on your requirements, sometimes wrap field in a box creates much issues in Titanium. To solve this upto some extent, you can use another parent view with **layout=composite** for fields  (**background='transparent'**) and set bottom padding to in minus so that you can remove the padding by shifting the field down.